# Adjuntar Imagen para APP en xamarin c#...y enviar automáticamente a un correo

Tags: c#, xamarin

hola soy total mente nuevo en este tema ..estoy desarrollando una APP y ya he logrado mucho pero estoy atracando en este tema.

Adjuntar Imagen para APP en xamarin c#...y enviar automáticamente a un correo 
envió código

cuando ejecuto sale este error imagen adjunta[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class Autorizacion : DialogFragment
{


    internal int mOnPagPpalComplete;
    private string mTxtCedula;
    private string mTxtNombre;
    // VARIABLES GENERALES
    int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    // DIRECTORIO DONDE SE GUARDARAN LAS IMAGENES
    String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "AlmacenFotos";

    //VARIABLE QUE CONTIENE LA URL DONDE ESTA ALMACENADA LA IMAGEN
    private Uri fileUri;

    //VARIABLES DE NUESTROS CONTROLES
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button Adjuntar;

    public Autorizacion(string mTxtNombre, string mTxtCedula)
    {
        this.mTxtNombre = mTxtNombre;
        this.mTxtCedula = mTxtCedula;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var textView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Autorizaciones, container, false);
        textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAutoNombre).Text = mTxtNombre;
        textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAutoCedula).Text = mTxtCedula;


        Adjuntar = textView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamara);

        imageView = textView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImgMostrarFotos);

        Adjuntar.Click += (s, args) => {

            CapturamosImagen();
        };
        return textView;

    }

    private void CapturamosImagen()
    {
        //FUNCION QUE SE ENCARGA DE CAPTURAR LA IMAGEN USANDO UN INTENT
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
        fileUri = GetOutputMediaFile(Activity, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, String.Empty);
        intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, fileUri);

        //LANZAMOS NUESTRO ITEM PARA CAPTURA LA IMAGEN
        StartActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    //OBTENEMOS LA URI DE NUESTRA FUTURA IMAGEN 
    Uri GetOutputMediaFile(Context context, string subdir, string name)
    {
        subdir = subdir ?? String.Empty;
        //SI NO SE LE ASIGNA UN NOMBRE DE IMAGEN, EL SISTEMA ASIGNA UNO
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
            name = "IMG_" + timestamp + ".jpg";
        }

        //OBTENEMOS EL PATH DONDE SE ENCUENTRA EL DIRECTORIO DE PICTURES DENTRO DE NUESTRO DISPOSITIVO
        string mediaType = Environment.DirectoryPictures;

        //OBTENEMOS EL PATH ABSOLUTO EN COMBINACION CON EL SUBDIRECTORIO DONDE GUARDAREMOS LAS IMAGENES
        using (Java.IO.File mediaStorageDir = new Java.IO.File(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(mediaType), subdir))
        {
            //VERIFICAMOS QUE EXISTA EL SUBDIRECTORIO
            if (!mediaStorageDir.Exists())
            {
                //SI NO EXISTE CREAMOS EL DIRECTORIO
                if (!mediaStorageDir.Mkdirs())
                    throw new Java.IO.IOException("NO se pudo crear el directorio, asegurece que tenga permisos la APP para crear archivos");

            }

            //REGRESAMOS LA URI DE LA NUEVA IMAGEN QUE SE USARA PARA GUARDAR LA FOTO
            return Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(GetUniquePath(mediaStorageDir.Path, name)));
        }
    }

    //VERIFICAMOS QUE SEA UN PATH UNICO PARA LA NUEVA IMAGEN DE LA FOTOGRAFIA
    string GetUniquePath(string path, string name)
    {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(name);
        if (ext == String.Empty)
            ext = ".jpg";

        name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name);

        string nname = name + ext;
        int i = 1;
        while (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, nname)))
            nname = name + "_" + (i++) + ext;

        return Path.Combine(path, nname);
    }


    public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // VERIFICAMOS EL CODIGO DE CAPTURA DE LA IMAGEN
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            //SI LA FOTO SE CAPTURO PROCEDEMOS A MOSTRA LA IMAGEN DE ESTA
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                // DESPLEGAMOS LA IMAGEN QUE CAPTURAMOS DE NUESTRA FOTO
                previewCapturedImage();
            }
            else if (resultCode == Result.Canceled)
            {
                // CUANDO LA CAPTURA ES CANCELADA

                Toast.MakeText(Activity, "La captura de la imagen fue cancelada.", ToastLength.Short)
                    .Show();
            }
            else
            {
                // CUANDO ALGO FALLO EN LA CAPTURA DE LA IMAGEN
                Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Se produjo un fallo en la captura de la imagen.", ToastLength.Short)
                    .Show();
            }

        }

    }

    void previewCapturedImage()
    {
        //MUESTRA LA IMAGEN QUE CAPTURAMOS
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.InSampleSize = 8;
        //CREAMOS NEUSTRO BITMAP
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fileUri.Path, options);
        //LE ASIGNAMOS EL BITMAP A NUESTRO CONTROL IMAGE
        imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }


    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_animation;

    }

    void DisplayImageInButton()
    {



    }
}
```

}

Comment: Has probado a pulsar en "Depurar > Eliminar todos los puntos de interrupción"? No creo que sea eso, pero el error es extraño.

Comment: Excelente tu ayuda tenia un punto de interrupción que ya no existía.